# softDeletes() requires deleted_at to be present in the request to save data

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, json-api

I'm trying to add deleted_at field to mysql database. I'm using laravel 5.2 &  https://github.com/nilportugues/laravel5-jsonapi in my api

Migration file has these:

```
$table->timestamps();
$table->softDeletes();
```

Model class:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Scene extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    /**
     * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
```

1 -This one saves data to database on post request:

```
{
"data": {
 "type": "scene",
 "attributes": {
  "title": "scene_N9DbG After S",
  "version": "rLEjNpeebq",
  "deleted_at": null
  }
 }
}
```

2 -This one doesn't save data to database on post:

```
{
"data": {
 "type": "scene",
 "attributes": {
  "title": "scene_N9DbG After S",
  "version": "rLEjNpeebq"
  }
 }
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
DataException in DataObject.php line 62:
An error with the provided data occured.

at DataObject::assertPost(array('type' => 'scene', 'attributes' => array( 'title' => 'scene_N9DbG After S', 'version' => 'rLEjNpeebq', 'created_at' => '2016-09-16 05:46:51', 'updated_at' => '2016-09-16 05:46:51')), object(JsonApiSerializer), 'App\Scene', object(ErrorBag)) in CreateResource.php line 58
```

Is this caused because of laravel or the package I'm using? How do I save data without sending `deleted_at`? I think I don't have to send deleted_at on every request.  Please let me know if more data is required.

Followed documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#soft-deleting

Answer (score 1):

It's from your package. From the documentation:

> POST requires all member attributes to be accepted, even those hidden by the mapper.

If you would like to change this, it looks like you need to define a `getRequiredProperties()` method on your Transformer object.

```
/**
 * List the fields that are mandatory in a persitence action (POST/PUT). 
 * If empty array is returned, all fields are mandatory.
 */
public function getRequiredProperties()
{
    return ['title', 'version'];
}
```

I've never used the package before, so I can't test if that actually works, but that is what I've been able to gather after looking through the documentation, code, and issues for a few minutes.

Comment: @red-cannibal It looks like support for this functionality was just added to [nilportugues/json-api](https://github.com/nilportugues/php-json-api) in version 2.4.4, which was tagged 14 days ago. You must be using [nilportugues/laravel5-json-api](https://github.com/nilportugues/laravel5-jsonapi/blob/2.4.4/composer.json) version >= 2.4.4 (this is the first version that depends on nilportugues/json-api ^2.4), and have recently updated your dependencies (`composer update nilportugues/laravel5-json-api`).

Comment: This one throws different error `Could not add required property 0 in class App\Model\Database\Scene because it does not exist`

Comment: I'm able to save data without created_at & updated_at though

Comment: I can't accept this answer cause it doesn't solve my problem. If I add `getRequiredProperties()`, I get this error `could not add required property o in class` which doesn't allow me to add data to database but if I leave it empty `return[]` instead of `return['title', 'version']`, it saves data if I send `deleted_at`. Thank you for you time

Comment: @red-cannibal The `created_at` and `updated_at` fields aren't required because the package you're using adds them in automatically (if you're using timestamps). According to the documentation, what I posted is what should work. However, as I mentioned, I have never used this package, so I can't really test anything. If returning an empty array works for you, that sounds like a bug (or a documentation error).